# CSS: Transition between different Classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i actually found alot of Questions like this but not the Answer i need.

About 1 Week ago i asked about an Gallery and now "nearly" finished it and i only have 1 Problem.

When you start the Gallery you can choose between 4 Categories. 
You click on one of them and the Specific Gallery shows.

I did this with this Code:

```
<div class="Category wow pulse" data-wow-delay="1s">
  <h1>SELECT AN CATEGORY</h1>
  <div class="Selection wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay="1.5s">
   <ul>
    <li class="selection-choose advertisement">Advertisement</li>
    <li class="selection-choose social">Social Media</li>
   </ul>
   <ul>
    <li class="selection-choose cinema4d">Cinema 4D</li>
    <li class="selection-choose manipulation">Manipulation</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>

<div class="Gallery">
  <div class="Advertisement-Gallery">
   ...

function showWorkGallery() {
 $('.advertisement').on('click', function() {
  $('.Advertisement-Gallery').addClass('make-visible');
 });
 $('.social').on('click', function() {
  $('.Social-Media-Gallery').addClass('make-visible');
 });
 $('.cinema4d').on('click', function() {
  $('.Cinema-4D-Gallery').addClass('make-visible');
 });
 $('.manipulation').on('click', function() {
  $('.Manipulation-Gallery').addClass('make-visible');
 });
}

.Advertisement-Gallery, .Social-Media-Gallery, .Cinema-4D-Gallery, .Manipulation-Gallery
  display: none
  width: 37%
  margin-top: 0
  opacity: 0
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out

 .make-visible
  display: block !important
  opacity: 1 !important
  margin-top: 10px !important
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out
```

So as you can (hopefully the Code is kind off messy and i think it can be done alot smaller) i'm trying to make a transition between the state of now shown and visible.
All answers i found had the Solution with opacity: 0 and then opacity: 1.
This is not working because they have to be display: none at first (you still can click on them when they're opacity: 0 and they're spreading the Website far to the bottom). 
Somehow it should be possible to only transition the opacity and margin (i know that you can do transition: opacity etc. but this is not working to)

Thanks to everyone who can help me out <3

EDIT: Here's an JSFiddle :) https://jsfiddle.net/as7Luccj/

Comment: http://www.greywyvern.com/?post=337

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking for, but you can use `display: none` to hide the element and `display: block` to show it.

Comment: Please provide a JsFiddle so we can easily help you :-)

Comment: simeg :That's exactly what i've done.
@Paulie_D Thanks for your help but this don't work because the other images still pushes the active Gallery in the wrong position and the scroll bar goes wayyy to the bottom where the last Image is ;(

Comment: @Ronen Cypis I don't know what this is but give me a minute or 2 (maybe also 10 :D)

Comment: @PixelStudio http://jsfiddle.net/ put your full code here, simulate the problem, explain us what's wrong and send the link :-)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/as7Luccj/

I guess i cannot upload the necessary images up there?
But still this shouldn't be that much of a problem.

So as you can see at the start you have the categories.
When clicking on one the Images of the Category show's up and i want a transition on it :)
@RonenCypis

Answer (score 0):

You can change both the `display` **AND** `opacity`, but put the css transition only on the `opacity` property. This way you will see the visual effect of the opacity, and the elements that are with `display:none;` will not be clickable.

Comment: Sry but this don't work (as i already mentioned in my Question ;))

Comment: We can't do your job here, try to put together a JsFiddle, so it will be easier to understand where EXACTLY you're stuck... it's hard to guess it...